# How do I limit the result to just different results?

Tags: mysql, sql

The database itself is about storing cocktails with their own recipes (Recipe) and ingredients (RecipeIngredient). Each user (User) has their own "pantry" (UserIngredients) in which they can store the ingredients they have at home. This query should now show them the cocktails they can mix

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT u.User_Name, r.Recipe_Name
FROM User u
    INNER JOIN UserIngredient ui ON u.User_ID = ui.User_ID
    INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient ri ON ui.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i ON ri.Ingredient_ID = i.Ingredient_ID
    INNER JOIN Recipe r ON ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
WHERE u.User_Session = 'DgRkQztkvUhotfSf53l7ciiI8rOhKtuvoPqCTvdlBXWTn9cYxz'
```

and would like to know if it is possible to just get one "r.Recipe_Name" per recipe and not one for each ingredient.

My tablelayout is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    User_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    User_Pass TEXT NOT NULL,
    User_Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    User_Surname TEXT NOT NULL,
    User_Nickname TEXT,
    User_EMail TEXT,
    User_Session VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    User_Admin BOOLEAN
);
CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
    Recipe_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Recipe_Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    Recipe_Clicks INT,
    Recipe_Description TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE Ingredient
(
    Ingredient_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Ingredient_Name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    Ingredient_Description TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE RecipeIngredient
(
    RecipeIngredient_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RecipeIngredient_Amount DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    MeasuringUnit_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Recipe_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Ingredient_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (MeasuringUnit_ID) REFERENCES MeasuringUnit(MeasuringUnit_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Recipe_ID) REFERENCES Recipe(Recipe_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Ingredient_ID) REFERENCES Ingredient(Ingredient_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE UserIngredient
(
    UserIngredient_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Ingredient_ID INT NOT NULL,
    User_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Ingredient_ID) REFERENCES Ingredient(Ingredient_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(User_ID) REFERENCES User(User_ID)
);
```

Comment: The most simple solution would add a [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to your select.

Comment: I know about DISTINCT, but I would like to know if there is a better solution to limit the results to different results?

Comment: Add userid column to recipe table then you can just join two tables instead of 4

Comment: @SvenNiehus yes, use a subselect. What you're really after is "Show me recipes that (= where clause) have ingredients that match what this user has." You express the constraint "user to recipe" in the join clause, where it doesn't belong, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT u.User_Name, MAX(r.Recipe_Name)
FROM User u
    INNER JOIN UserIngredient ui ON u.User_ID = ui.User_ID
    INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient ri ON ui.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i ON ri.Ingredient_ID = i.Ingredient_ID
    INNER JOIN Recipe r ON ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
WHERE u.User_Session = 'DgRkQztkvUhotfSf53l7ciiI8rOhKtuvoPqCTvdlBXWTn9cYxz'
GROUP BY u.User_Name, r.Recipe_Name
```

Not sure about this but it sounds like multiple ingredients will have the same recipe so just select max, which will return the only recipe name and if you group by user name + recipe name it might give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result using this database, try

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.User_Name, r.Recipe_Name
FROM User u
    INNER JOIN UserIngredient ui ON u.User_ID = ui.User_ID
    INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient ri ON ui.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID
    INNER JOIN Ingredient i ON ri.Ingredient_ID = i.Ingredient_ID
    INNER JOIN Recipe r ON ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
WHERE u.User_Session = 'DgRkQztkvUhotfSf53l7ciiI8rOhKtuvoPqCTvdlBXWTn9cYxz'
```

My guess is that users create Recipies, why don't you instead add User_ID to Receipe?

Comment: No the user does not create the recipies, they are created by administrators via an admin panel. Thanks for your solution, but is there a better solution to limit the results to different results?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.User_Name, r.Recipe_Name
FROM User u
INNER JOIN UserIngredient ui ON u.User_ID = ui.User_ID
INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient ri ON ui.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID
INNER JOIN Ingredient i ON ri.Ingredient_ID = i.Ingredient_ID
INNER JOIN Recipe r ON ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
WHERE u.User_Session = 'DgRkQztkvUhotfSf53l7ciiI8rOhKtuvoPqCTvdlBXWTn9cYxz'
```